# Неявная ошибка. System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format." Не могу понять в чем проблема, тк новичок в программировании

Tags: c#, c

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    class Program
    {
        static string csvPath = "wind_turbines.csv";
        static DataTable data;
    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            data = LoadDataset(csvPath);
    
            Console.WriteLine(GetMin(data, 0));
    
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    
        static double GetMin(DataTable dt, int col)
        {
            double minVal = double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[0][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var val = double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[i][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
                if (val < minVal)
                {
                    minVal = val;
                }
            }
    
            return minVal;
        }
        static double GetMax(DataTable dt, int col)
        {
            double maxVal = double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[0][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var val = double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[i][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
                if (val > maxVal)
                {
                    maxVal = val;
                }
            }
    
            return maxVal;
        }
        static double GetMean(DataTable dt, int col)
        {
            double val = 0;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                val += double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[i][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
    
            return val;
        }
    
        static int GetIndexOfMax(DataTable dt, int col)
        {
            int index = 0;
            double maxVal = double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[0][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var val = double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[i][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
                if (val > maxVal)
                {
                    maxVal = val;
                    index = i;
                }
            }
    
            return index;
        }
        static int GetIndexOfMin(DataTable dt, int col)
        {
            int index = 0;
            double minVal = double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[0][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var val = double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[i][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
                if (val < minVal)
                {
                    minVal = val;
                    index = i;
                }
            }
    
            return index;
        }
    
        static string[] FindQnique(DataTable dt, int col)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string element = dt.Rows[i][col] as string;
                if (list.IndexOf(element) == -1)
                {
                    list.Add(element);
                }
            }
    
            return list.ToArray();
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Загрузить датасет из CSV
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="csvPath">Путь к файлу CSV</param>
        /// <returns>Объект DataTable после преобразования файла CSV</returns>
        static DataTable LoadDataset(string filePath)
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
    
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                var header = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
    
                foreach (var h in header)
                    data.Columns.Add(h);
    
                string line;
    
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var entries = line.Split(';');
    
                    DataRow row = data.NewRow();
    
                    for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; ++i)
                        row[i] = entries[i].ToString();
    
                    data.Rows.Add(row);
                }
    
                return data;
            }
        }
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnXGc.png
```

Comment: хотя бы укажите, на какой строчке ошибка

Comment: double minVal = double.Parse((string)dt.Rows[0][col], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Ну по всей видимости здесь `(string)dt.Rows[0][col]` оказывается не `double`, вот и ошибка при попытке распарсить. Вероятно какая-то беда с содержимым  файла `wind_turbines.csv`, можете приложить его сюда, а лучше сами в отладчике посмотрите что там в этой строке, посмотрите что там в файле и прикиньте то ли это, что вы ожидали, и почему это не то.

Answer (score 0):

(type).Parce метод скидывает `FormatException`. Когда строка не соответствует формату.

используйте `TryParse (string s, out result)` и проверяйте результат во избежании ошибки формата.

PS. наиминг god level

```
static string[] FindQnique(DataTable dt, int col)
```